# Ubunto GUI on Dell Inspiron 660 not working

Tags: drivers, gnome, gui

I am new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu on an old dell inspiron 660 it has i5-3340 processer and the graphics, and network interface are integrated in the mother board.
all the online examples of install show some sort of gui, but my install did not have that.  just straight up terminal screen.  Doing some onlilne searches I found gnome is the default.  correct me if I misunderstood.  In trying to get that to run I had to install it and then it will not run as there is an I/O error.  Is this a driver issue or did I mess up the install?  I plan to run a NAS, and possibly run pihole in a docker environment.  I am not very far along here and would do the install over if I may have messed it up the first time.  thanks for any advice.

Comment: You've provided no product/release details; nor given clues as to what checks you made. Did you install a desktop system? verify the ISO prior to write to installation media? did the media verify complete successfully?  (IO error implies a problem in early steps for your *unstated* Ubuntu product). GNOME is also a somewhat *heavy* desktop; so does your machine meet the minimum requirements for the system you installed (*otherwise the GUI won't run & shouldn't be expected to, that includes dedicated RAM on GPU*). Please provide specific details.

Comment: FYI:  If you installed Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core... there is no GUI.  The ISO downloaded & installed dictates what is installed; with many installers available, many GUI options (*including no GUI; non-default GUI available via flavor ISOs*), plus the release you're installing (ie. *options available for one release may differ to other releases; but you gave no clues*).  ISO can also dictate the default kernel stack (*which can make a difference for some hardware*).  Currently we have no ideas as to what Ubuntu product, what release, which ISO etc. you used.

Comment: Did you scan https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  to ensure your hardware meets the minimum requirements? including things like "*3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB*" ?   Some integrated graphics provides this, others do not - but we can't know if you checked unless you tell us.   FYI:  If your hardware doesn't meet the requirements, lighter *flavor* options can still provide alternatives.  The IO error to me reads as key, but you gave no clear message, nor when you see it, thus we can't help there sorry.